# Testing React component onClick event with multiple actions in it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap, reactjs-testutils

Can't figure it out how to test onClick function with multiple actions in it.

```
onButtonClick = function(action){
  this.props.otherAction();
  action();
}
...
<Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small" onClick={onButtonClick.bind(this,someAction}>
  Something
</Button>
```

And the test I currently have is like this.

```
const onButtonClick = function (action) {
  actions.otherAction();
  action();
};

it('Should include a button with multiple actions on onClick event.', function () {
    const button = shallowTestUtils.findAllWithType(_component, Button);
    expect(button[0].props.onClick).to.equal(onButtonClick.bind(this, actions.someAction));
});
```

The result i get is this.

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to equal [Function]
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that every call of `Function.prototype.bind` returns you a new function. So these functions are not equal

```
function onClick() {
}

console.log(onClick.bind() === onClick.bind()) // prints false
```

If you want to check that button receives your click handler, you can trigger simulated click and check the result of the action. Also, you can mock `onClick` to spy function.

```
it('should trigger handler on button click', function () {
  // mock actual action
  _component.onClick = sinon.spy();

  // find button and trigger click on it
  const button = shallowTestUtils.findAllWithType(_component, Button)[0];
  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(findDOMNode(button));
  expect(_component.onClick.called).to.be.ok();
});
```

**UPD.** If you want to test your component against the store, to be sure that proper actions were dispatched, you can do it in the following way.

First, create you mock store:

```
const mockStore = {
   dispatch: sinon.spy(),
   getState() {
     // here you can return some mock state
   }
}
```

Then pass this store down to your component. (I assume that your `MyComponent` is connected to store)

```
const component = TestUtils.createRenderer().render(<MyComponent store={mockStore}>)

const button = shallowTestUtils.findAllWithType(component, Button)[0];
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(findDOMNode(button));
// here you can check that dispatch was called with all expected actions
expect(mockStore.dispatch.calledWith({type: 'ACTION_TYPE'})).to.be.ok();
```

See [Sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) to learn more about spy checks.

Comment: Doing this throws another error: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. But even so, this will only check if click happens, would be really great to check if certains actions are actually called.

Comment: Well, then you can instantiate your component with a fake store with a spy on `dispatch`. Updated the answer.